# django - validate char field as email

Tags: python, django

Lets say i have model:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

then i create form:

```
class SubscriptionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = ['address']
    def clean_address(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['address']
        #VALIDATE HERE IF IT IS EMAIL
        return email
```

How can i apply [email validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/#validate-email) to my field **without changing model**?

EDIT: Is this even possible?

Comment: Why to reinvent the wheel when you have `EmailField`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#emailfield

Comment: Just call the email validator manually in your form?... what have you tried?

Comment: But how can i do it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off just setting the validator in the model. Adding a validator doesn't affect the database in anyway so it isn't really changing the database model.

but if you really want to just call the validator then do that.

```
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator
def clean_address(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['address']

    EmailValidator()(email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a validator to the `validator` field of your `CharField`:

```
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator

emailvalidator = EmailValidator(message="invalid email")

class Subscription(models.Model):
     address = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[emailvalidator])
```

But you should consider using the `EmailField` instead.

Comment: But can i do it in SubscriptionForm class?

Comment: `SubscriptionForm` is a `ModelForm` so it can take its validation from the model. If you want to specify the validator explicitly in your form field you should consider using a subclass of `Form` and pass the same email validator to the `address` form field